# PHP Form without changing pages

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, fancybox

How do I set up my PHP, HTML, and JQuery so that the page doesn't change when the user clicks submit? My form is within a lightbox plugin called Fancybox (fancybox.net)

The full example is at [my church's website](http://www.gracepensacola.com/test/contact_us.php)

Here's my PHP.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "nonya@yahoo.com";
    $email_also ="nonya2@yahoo.com";
    $email_subject = $first_name + " " + $last_name + " Website Inquiry";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
@mail($email_also, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>


<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


$("#question_form_link").fancybox({
        'scrolling' : 'no',
        'titleShow' : true,
        'onClosed'  : function() {
        }
    });


    }); //end ready 

</script>
```

And my form:

```
  <div style="display:none">
    <form id="question_form" name="question_form" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
      <table width="450px">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><label for="first_name">First Name *</label></td>
          <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><label for="last_name">Last Name *</label></td>
          <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><label for="email">Email Address *</label></td>
          <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label></td>
          <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><label for="comments">Comments *</label></td>
          <td valign="top"><textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're looking for AJAX

Comment: Please include your JavaScript/jQuery code.

Comment: I added my jQuery, though it only Fancybox to open the form. AJAX? I've heard of it, but will look into it. Any example applying to this would also be nice.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm
You're going to have to make a php file. In that php file, get the form data and do what you want with it.

Comment: Okay. I already have a PHP file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need ajax. Firstly, assign all of the input fields an ID so that they can be selected easily by jQuery. Then add the following to your JS.

```
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
// Get all of the values from the input fields thru their ID's
   var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
   var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
   var email = $("#email").val();
   var telephone = $("#telephone").val();
   var comments = $("#comments").val();

// Validate the form to make sure that all of the required fields are not left empty
   if(first_name != ''
   && last_name != ''
   && email != ''
   && comments != '')
   {
       $.ajax({
          url: "email.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: ({
               first_name: first_name,
               last_name: last_name,
               email: email,
               telephone: telephone,
               comments: comments
           }),
          success: function(data) 
          {
          // You might wanna display a message telling the user that the form was successfully filled out.
          }
      });
    }

    if(first_name == ''
    || last_name == ''
    || email == ''
    || comments == '')
    {
        alert("You left one of the required fields empty");
    }
 });
```

Comment: Those are all data that are passed along to the php file. The values on the left are named by whatever your $_POST variables in the php file are. Then you set them accordingly. In this case, the first_name variable in JS is equivalent to the value of the input field with the ID of "first_name"

Comment: I added document.write('<p class="thank_you">Thank you for contacting us. We will get in touch with you as soon as possible.<p>'); where you said to put comment and it just closes out. Also, the check doesn't do anything. It just doesn't let me close it by clicking submit. No alert box pops up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .serialize() to get data from your form.

```
$.post('send_form_email.php' , $("#question_form").serialize())
.done(function( data ) {
    alert("ok");
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error");
})
.always(function() {
    alert("always show this message");
});
```